Rules necessary to follow while doing Vedic mantra chanting?
There are many suktams and mantras in the rig vedas and Atharva vedas , which help an individual attain powers. So to attain these powers what kind of japa is beneficial , vachika japa, upamsu japa, or the Manasa japa?
